# C#/ASP.NET MVC 4 Instantiate Object Derived From Interface In Factory Method

Tags: asp.net, c#-4.0, asp.net-mvc-4, factory-pattern

Currently have a Factory class that features a `GetSelector` function, which returns a concrete implementation of `ISelector`. I have several different classes that implement ISelector and based on a setting I would like to receive the appropriate `ISelector` back.

```
public interface ISelector
{
    string GetValue(string Params);
}

public class XmlSelector : ISelector
{
    public string GetValue(string Params)
    {
        // open XML file and get value
    }
}

public static class SelectorFactory
{
    public static ISelector GetSelector()
    {
        return new XmlSelector(); // Needs changing to look at settings
    }
}
```

My question is what is the best way to store the setting? I am aware of using AppSettings etc. but I'm not sure whether I want to have to store strings in the web.config and perform a switch on it - just seems to be really tightly coupled in that if a new implementation of ISelector is made, then the Factory would need to be changed. Is there any way of perhaps storing an assembly name and instantiating based on that?

Thanks,

Chris

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It is hard to say, because I don't know the architecture of your particular project, but at a first glance what I would do is **if** the objects associated with ISelector can be decoupled from your web application, I would put these objects in a class library along with the factory. Your factory will need to be changed if you implement a new ISelector, but if you can decouple the whole ISelector family from your actual web application the depth of the refactoring you will have to do will be minimal compared to a monolithic architecture.

Personally, I tend to avoid AppSettings, web.config settings and the like for mission-critical design questions. Using the web.config as an example, I have seen applications where architectural data is stored for ease of configurability. The problem is that after compilation your web.config can be changed (that is the purpose of it after all) and if the implementation of your classes depends on very specific values being chosen, you are running a risk of a crash when someone inadvertently modifies the wrong value.

Like I said all this depends entirely on your application architecture, but my reflex would be to split out the components that could be subject to future modification into a class library. Loose coupling is your friend ;).

Comment: Thanks @levib however my factory and associated classes/interfaces have already been extracted into a class library. I just need a simple way of somebody being able to switch from say an XML provider to a Database provider, whilst maintaining the flexibility of further ISelector's to be written

Comment: How do you need to do the switch? Is it something which should be client-configurable or is it something that you would do in the code itself? (I am assuming the latter given the fact that you are referring to the possibility of writing future classes...)

Comment: Yes, it would be code-based. I'm looking at releasing a library of code for other developers, but based on their needs they may need to either use a DB, XML or some other persistence method - I just want to make it easy for them to change (as the implementation will be referenced in several places) rather than having to go through all the code and change the concrete implementations!

Comment: Why not use dependency injection in that case ? I use Ninject for this. (As an aside, I love Ninject because the config is done in the application code and not in an external config file.) Basically you set up a DI factory which specifies that every time you request an object of type [interface], a certain implementation of that interface is returned. This may or may not work for you depending on what is going to be closed source and what is going to be open source, but if you can use it it is really a great method. The book Pro ASP.NET MVC 3 Framework explains Ninject + MVC really well.

Answer (score 0):

Instead of doing it in AppSettings, I think a better approach will be to create a separate XML file, which will only hold the mappings and from that file you can iterate through the mappings and return correct instance in `GetSelector()`.